# replace empty column with other column and add string to it

Tags: linux, shell, unix, replace, scripting

I have  a dat file as below.

```
1436667|disne-2h.xco.caDIAS0000000000897089-DIAS0000000000897090|""|""|""|""|....
|disne-2h.xco.caDIAS0000000000897089-DIAS0000000000897091|""|""|||
```

Here "|" is the field seperator.

I have a scenario as below.

I need to check if first column is empty then I have to replace with second column if second column is not empty and add a string to it.

I tried something like below.

```
 awk -F '|' '$2 && !$1{ $1=$2 }1' Asset.csv
```

The above command is removing the field separators and getting output without field separators. If I add string to it like below.

```
awk -F '|' '$2 && !$1{ $1=$2+"_ABC" }1' Asset.csv
```

First column is coming as 0.

Could you please suggest the way to do it and add a string to it in first column.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suppose if first field is empty like in 2nd row..Output should be like .disne-2h.xco.caDIAS0000000000897089-DIAS0000000000897091_ABC|disne-2h.xco.caDIAS0000000000897089-DIAS0000000000897091|""|""|||

Comment: @anubhava: I am trying with awk from so long .. its not working out..

Comment: I have posted an awk solution below. Please pay attention to `BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}` and single condition+action block.

Answer (score 0):

Question Clarity doesn't exist.

## I tried this Code to check first field is empty or not , Hope this help  .Thank's

```
cat datfile
```

1436667|disne-2h.xco.caDIAS0000000000897089-DIAS0000000000897090|""|""|""|""|....disne-2h.xco.caDIAS0000000000897089-DIAS0000000000897091 disne-2h.xco.caDIAS0000000000897089-DIAS0000000000897091 "" ""

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR=`cat datfile`
#echo $VAR



IFS='|' read -r FIRST SECOND THIRD FOURTH FIFTH SIXTH SEVENTH <<< "$VAR"

echo $FIRST
echo $SECOND
echo $THIRD
echo $FOURTH
echo $FIFTH
echo $SIXTH
echo $SEVENTH



# CHECK First string is empty

if [ -z "$FIRST" ]
then
echo "\$FIRST is empty"
else
echo "\$FIRST is not empty"
fi


 ./testlab.sh
 1436667
disne-2h.xco.caDIAS0000000000897089-DIAS0000000000897090
""
""
""
""
....disne-2h.xco.caDIAS0000000000897089-DIAS0000000000897091 disne-2h.xco.caDIAS0000000000897089-DIAS0000000000897091 "" ""
$FIRST is not empty
```

Comment: In script file  , Use IFS (delimiter | ) split the string in Field (FIRST, SECOND , and so on ) .  Perform the manipulation operation on the value assigned to this variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F '|' '$1=="" {$1=$2}; $1== $2 { $1=$1"_ABC"} ;1' OFS='|' Asset.csv
```

This worked for me.. thanks

You can still share if you have more optimized solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} $1=="" && $2!=""{$1=$2 "_ABC"} 1' file
```

```
1436667|disne-2h.xco.caDIAS0000000000897089-DIAS0000000000897090|""|""|""|""|....
disne-2h.xco.caDIAS0000000000897089-DIAS0000000000897091_ABC|disne-2h.xco.caDIAS0000000000897089-DIAS0000000000897091|""|""|||
```